# Leaderboard status "Not Live"

Tags: app-store-connect, live, leaderboard

I've developed a game for the Apple appstore. It's already reviewed and accepted by apple (pending my release)

.. but

As I try to enter the leaderboard in my game, it says "*Game Center Unavailable. Player is not signed in*". And as I check the status of my approved game in itunesconnect its satus is "*Not Live*".

Can anyone please help me?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Not Live doesn't matter. It works anyway.

Check a few things:

Enable GameCenter in Capabilities.
did you use the localPlayer authenticateHandler?

> self.localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
>   use your real Account. No sandboxTester.

This Is my Setup and it works Fine.